# Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.test03datetime/com.example.test03datetime.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, android

я только еще учусь и пытаюсь сделать выбор даты и времени в Activity но при компиляции выводится ошибка 
**Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.test03datetime/com.example.test03datetime.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException** 
и компилятор ругяется на метод **setInitialDate();** если его закомментировать то активити запускается но при нажатии на выбор даты приложение падает. Делаю в аналогии с примером который описан [тут](https://metanit.com/java/android/18.1.php)

Буду признателен за любую помощь.

Ниже прилагаю лог компилятора и исходный код

```html
04-22 07:41:33.499 3584-3584/? D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x71 at 0x0014
04-22 07:41:33.507 3584-3584/? D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
04-22 07:41:33.507 3584-3584/? W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xa4cf7b20)
04-22 07:41:33.511 3584-3584/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.test03datetime, PID: 3584
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.test03datetime/com.example.test03datetime.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2184)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.example.test03datetime.MainActivity.setInitialDate(MainActivity.java:64)
        at com.example.test03datetime.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:27)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2148)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601) 
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**activity_main**

```
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="395dp"
android:layout_height="715dp"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
android:orientation="horizontal"
app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editTextDate"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:text="Date"
    android:onClick="onClickDate"/>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editTextTime"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:text="Time"
    android:onClick="onClickTime"/>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.test03datetime;

import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
import android.app.TimePickerDialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.text.format.DateUtils;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TimePicker;

import java.util.Calendar;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    EditText remindDate;
    EditText remindTime;
    Calendar date, time = Calendar.getInstance();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );
        setContentView( R.layout.activity_main );
        remindDate = findViewById( R.id.editTextDate );
        remindTime = findViewById( R.id.editTextTime );

        setInitialDate();
        setInitialTime();

    }
    // установка начальнго времени
    private void setInitialTime() {
        remindTime.setText( DateUtils.formatDateTime( this,
                time.getTimeInMillis(),
                DateUtils.FORMAT_SHOW_TIME
        ) );
    }
    public void onClickTime(View view) { // выбор времени
        new TimePickerDialog( MainActivity.this, t,
                time.get( Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY ),
                time.get( Calendar.MINUTE ), true ).show();
    }

    //установка обработчика времени
    TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener t = new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
            time.set( Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hourOfDay );
            time.set( Calendar.MINUTE, minute );
            setInitialTime();
        }
    };

    // установка начальной даты
    private void setInitialDate() {

        remindDate.setText( DateUtils.formatDateTime( this,
                date.getTimeInMillis(),
                DateUtils.FORMAT_SHOW_DATE | DateUtils.FORMAT_SHOW_YEAR
        ) );
    }
    public void onClickDate(View view) { // выбор даты
        new DatePickerDialog( MainActivity.this, d,
                date.get( Calendar.YEAR ),
                date.get( Calendar.MONTH ),
                date.get( Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH ) ).show();
    }
    // установка обработчика даты
    DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener d = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
            date.set( Calendar.YEAR, year );
            date.set( Calendar.MONTH, month );
            date.set( Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth );
            setInitialDate();
        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас непроинициализирована переменная `date` из-за того что вы определили в одной строке `Calendar date, time = Calendar.getInstance();`.

Из-за этого строка

```
date.getTimeInMillis()
```

вызывает данное исключение

Comment: Спасибо исправил  Calendar date = Calendar.getInstance();
    Calendar time = Calendar.getInstance(); и все заработало. Благодарю за помощь

Comment: @Zenk0, [Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, который лучше всего решает вашу проблему, отметьте его «верным»](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/7025/11515)